# working of ring oscillator

Tags: how-does-it-work

As far as I know TRNG(hardware random number generator) is used  to produce a sequence of random bits.This sequence of random bits can be used as random keys in cryptography for encryption purpose.Usually,PRNG(pseudorandom number generator) is used in encryption but the random numbers a PRNG produce are predictable and TRNG is less used because its working is slower than that of TRNG. Recently,I am trying to do a project on a password hashing.In this project I want to include TRNG instead of PRNG. Therefore,I need to know about the operation of TRNG in details.

Recently, I could know that ring oscillator can be used as TRNG. From Wikipedia, I tried to know about the working of a ring oscillator but I couldn't understand it completely.

Can anyone help me to understand the working of a ring oscillator with intuition or provide me with a source or link so that I can understand it.

Comment: Please google for "ring oscillator white noise", because white noise is what you want. There are a number of research papers on this.

Comment: OP's gone dark so question is unlikely to be edited.  Note that cryptography uses cryptographic ally secure PRNGs whose output is not predictable in any way whatsoever without knowing the internal state.

Answer (score 1):

> need to know about the operation of TRNG in details.

There are so many different trng that it will likely takes you a long time to finish it.

I typically rely on two types of them.

1. ADC. The last bit of any ADC module, unless designed by God, is random. On a typical low end MCU, you get ADC of 500ksps or higher, some I to 10s maps (lpc43xx for example).
2. Any RC oscillator has phase noise. So gate them to obtain the lab.

Both approaches can yield speed easily in excess of 100k bits per second.

Ring oscillator is nothing an oscillator that accumulated phase delays.

edit: here is where I did some investigation into the #2 approach mentioned above - https://dannyelectronics.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/true-random-number-generators/

hope it helps.

edit 2: the first approach (ADC-randomness) requires the adc module to be properly set-up. that rules out the use of Arduino -> it has significant sample-to-sample correlation to be useful here. But once you rewrite the adc code, it can be made useful again.

external adcs can be used as well. I have used a hx711 module for this purpose. the input pins don't need to be floating -> adc'ng any input will do, including the reference or ground.

Comment: Unfortunately though the lsb  of a floating ADC will actually be randomly random.  A TRNG needs to output entropy at a carefully measured rate so that (entropy in) > (entropy out).  If the ADC is just floating, you'll not be able to control the output stream and it might significantly vary if you wave your hand over the ADC, it rains or gets a little warmer.  Your TRNG would be very unreliable.